# what is the difference between factoring and dividing an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Newbie question: Is pulling out factors and dividing the same? Please explain the difference in the examples below.

Example:

$$2x-4  \to 2(x-2)$$

Is it the same as

$$4x^2 - 8x + 1 = 0$$

$$\frac{4x^2 - 8 }{4} = -\frac{1}{4} \implies x^2 - 2x = -\frac{1}{4}$$

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Factoring** is used to simplify polynomials for easy handling on one side of an equation. While **division** is one that comes with a two-sided equation where if you can divide one side for say $x$, you can divide the other side also by $x$. If you can tell by your examples, you can apply what I have said thus far. Although they are very similar, they have one or two different properties.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

"Factor" and "divisor" are synonyms. They are exactly the same concept. You can factor both polynomials like $x^2+7x+6$ and integers like $5432$, and both are non-trivial, and both will yield a set of unique prime factors that can't be factored further.